# backtransform formula with sign and abs against leptokurtic distribution

Tags: r, distribution, transformation, absolute, sign

I had problems with leptokurtic distribution and found a helpful transformation here: [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85687/how-to-transform-leptokurtic-distribution-to-normality][1] : `sign(Y−median(Y))⋅abs(Y−median(Y))^1/3`
Now I want to back-transform my fitted values of the models and tried the following:

```
if(fitted(Y)>=0)backtrans(Y)<-(fitted(Y))^3+median(Y) 

if(fitted(Y)<0)> backtrans(Y)<--1*(fitted(Y))^3+median(Y)
```

In some dependent variable back-transformed results make sense, but in others the outcome reverses the results I have if I look at my raw data and are not coherent, e.g. I would suggest (and other people found this) that cows with less experience in being milked have higher heart rates during milking than cows with a lot of milking routine.

Is there a mistake in the formula for back-transformation?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague and me found the solution:

```
for (i in 1:length(fitted(Y))){
  backtrans(Y)[i]<-(fitted(Y)[i]^3)+median(Y)
}
```